# Installation of openssl Ruby gem fails because it can't find openssl installed in Ubuntu

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, openssl

I'm doing this:

```
$ apt-get install -y openssl
$ gem install openssl -- --with-openssl-include=/usr/include/openssl
```

It fails:

```
...
checking for openssl/ssl.h... yes
checking for CRYPTO_malloc() in -lcrypto... yes
checking for SSL_new() in -lssl... yes
checking for LIBRESSL_VERSION_NUMBER in openssl/opensslv.h... no
checking for OpenSSL version >= 1.0.2... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.1/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
    --with-openssl-dir
    --with-openssl-include=${openssl-dir}/include
    --with-openssl-lib=${openssl-dir}/lib
    --with-kerberos-dir
    --without-kerberos-dir
    --with-kerberos-include
    --without-kerberos-include=${kerberos-dir}/include
    --with-kerberos-lib
    --without-kerberos-lib=${kerberos-dir}/lib
    --with-nsl-dir
    --without-nsl-dir
    --with-nsl-include
    --without-nsl-include=${nsl-dir}/include
    --with-nsl-lib
    --without-nsl-lib=${nsl-dir}/lib
    --with-nsllib
    --without-nsllib
    --with-socket-dir
    --without-socket-dir
    --with-socket-include
    --without-socket-include=${socket-dir}/include
    --with-socket-lib
    --without-socket-lib=${socket-dir}/lib
    --with-socketlib
    --without-socketlib
    --with-crypto-dir
    --without-crypto-dir
    --with-crypto-include
    --without-crypto-include=${crypto-dir}/include
    --with-crypto-lib
    --without-crypto-lib=${crypto-dir}/lib
    --with-cryptolib
    --without-cryptolib
    --with-ssl-dir
    --without-ssl-dir
    --with-ssl-include
    --without-ssl-include=${ssl-dir}/include
    --with-ssl-lib
    --without-ssl-lib=${ssl-dir}/lib
    --with-ssllib
    --without-ssllib
extconf.rb:136:in `<main>': OpenSSL >= 1.0.2 or LibreSSL >= 3.1.0 is required (RuntimeError)
```

What are the right arguments to pass to `gem install` to make it work? This works, by the way:

```
$ which openssl
/usr/bin/openssl
$ openssl version
OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022 (Library: OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022)
```

Comment: You probably need this: `sudo apt-get install openssl openssl-dev`

Comment: Is it possible that your version of openssl requires a VERY specific openssl binary version. When it says `>= 1.0.2` is means 1.x.x but not 3.x

Answer (score 3):

From the line:

```
--ruby=/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.1/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
```

I see you're using ruby 3.0.1 and you're trying to install openssl 3. Ruby versions lower that 3.1 doesn't go along with openssl3.  You can wether try to install 3.1 o newer or if 3.0.1 is mandatory for you, downgrade openssl to 1.0.

As you're using rvm, try:

```
rvm install 3.1.4 --with-openssl-dir=<the directory you have>
```

Then, you can try to install your `openssl` gem.

Comment: Many thanks! One last question, what is the `<the directory you have>` in your example? I assume, it should be the directory where `openssl` is installed in Ubuntu? I can't figure out, what is the right place of it.

Comment: that's correct, in my case as a mac user, I use `--with-openssl-dir=$(brew --prefix openssl@3)` but ubuntu will be a different case. You installed openssl via apt-get? maybe querying for the files in the package will give you the location.

Comment: Yes, it's Ubuntu. On macOS inside the directory returned by `brew --prefix openssl@3` I see `bin/`, `lib/`, and `include/` subdirectories. However, I can't find a similar disposition of directories in Ubuntu :( Where openssl is installed in Ubuntu, do you know?